# How do find out the total amount for each month using spark in python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking for a way to aggregate by month my data. I want firstly to keep only month in my visitdate. My DataFrame looks like this:

```
Row(visitdate = 1/1/2013, 
patientid = P1_Pt1959, 
amount = 200, 
note = jnut, 
)
```

My objectif subsequently is to group by visitdate and calculate the sum of amount. I tried this :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
.config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
.getOrCreate()

file_path = "G:/Visit Data.csv"
patients = spark.read.csv(file_path,header = True)
patients.createOrReplaceTempView("visitdate")

sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT visitdate,SUM(amount) as totalamount from visitdate GROUP BY visitdate")
sqlDF.show()
```

This is the result :

```
visitdate|totalamount|
+----------+-----------+
|  9/1/2013|    10800.0|
|25/04/2013|    12440.0|
|27/03/2014|    16930.0|
|26/03/2015|    18560.0|
|14/05/2013|    13770.0|
|30/06/2013|    13880.0
```

My objectif is to get something like this:

```
  visitdate|totalamount|
+----------+-----------+
|1/1/2013|    10800.0|
|1/2/2013|    12440.0|
|1/3/2013|    16930.0|
|1/4/2014|    18560.0|
|1/5/2015|    13770.0|
|1/6/2015|    13880.0|
```

Comment: seems like you want a `groupBy` and `sum`. Have you tried that? Is it not working? Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: What did you try?  can you put your code into the question?

Comment: after doing groupBy ans sum iam getting that o/p

Answer (score 0):

You need to truncate your date's down to months so they group properly, then do a groupBy/sum.  There is a spark function to do this for you call `date_trunc`.  For example.

```
from datetime import date
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_trunc, sum

data = [
    (date(2000, 1, 2), 1000),
    (date(2000, 1, 2), 2000),
    (date(2000, 2, 3), 3000),
    (date(2000, 2, 4), 4000),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(data), ["date", "amount"])

df.groupBy(date_trunc("month", df.date)).agg(sum("amount"))

+-----------------------+-----------+
|date_trunc(month, date)|sum(amount)|
+-----------------------+-----------+
|    2000-01-01 00:00:00|       3000|
|    2000-02-01 00:00:00|       7000|
+-----------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: How to truncate if we have some thousands of rows data.Is not possible to change one by one. |9/1/2013|    10800.0|
|25/04/2013|    12440.0|
|27/03/2014|    16930.0|
|26/03/2015|    18560.0|
|14/05/2013|    13770.0|
|30/06/2013|    13880.0|
|  8/2/2014|    18310.0|
|22/12/2014|    18510.0|
|  5/2/2013|    11810.0|
|  5/5/2013|    11910.0|
|20/01/2014|    15970.0|
|23/10/2014|    16050.0|
|30/01/2013|    11700.0|
|  2/2/2014|    14780.0|
|  5/5/2014|    14490.0|
|29/05/2014|    15920.0|
|25/03/2013|    13510.0|
|  6/7/2013|    13230.0|
|11/10/2013|    13880.0|

Comment: Iam getting like this
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_trunc, sum
total = patients.groupBy(date_trunc("month", patients.visitdate)).agg(sum("amount"))
total.show()
+----------------------------+-----------+
|date_trunc(month, visitdate)|sum(amount)|
+----------------------------+-----------+
|                        null| 1.522009E7|
+----------------------------+-----------+